# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ username: string; email: string;

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

Trying to add typescript to custom React Form Component and can't rid of mistake i don't know how to fix.
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ username: string; email: string; password: string; confirmPassword: string; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ username: string; email: string; password: string; confirmPassword: string; }'.

I'm sure there is an answer somewhere, but i can't adjust it to my code as well as can't understand the basic of mistake.
Please help me understand

App Component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import s from './App.module.scss'
import Input from "./components/Input/Input";

function App() {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
    });

    const inputs = [
        {
        id: "username",
        name: "UserName",
        type: "text",
        placeholder: "Username",
        },
        {
            id: "email",
            name: "Email",
            type: "text",
            placeholder: "@gmail.com",
        },
    ]

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    return (
        <div className={s.app}>
            <form action="">
                {inputs.map((input) => (
                    <Input
                        key={input.id}
                        id={input.id}
                        name={input.name}
                        placeholder={input.placeholder}
                        type={input.type}
                        value={values[input.name]}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                ))}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Input Component

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import s from './Input.module.scss';

interface InputProps {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    placeholder: string,
    type: string,
    value: string,
    onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void,
}

const Input: FC<InputProps> = ({id, name, placeholder, type, value, onChange}) => {
    return (
        <div className={s.input}>
            <label htmlFor={id}>
                {name}
            </label>
            <input
                id={id}
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Input;
```

Source code: https://github.com/Endo-Resu/react-custom-form

Thank you for ur time, advices and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

App component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import s from "./App.module.scss";
import Input from "./components/Input/Input";

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: ""
  });

  const inputs: {
    id: string;
    name: keyof typeof values;
    type: string;
    placeholder: string;
  }[] = [
    {
      id: "username",
      name: "username",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Username"
    },
    {
      id: "email",
      name: "email",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "@gmail.com"
    }
  ];

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className={s.app}>
      <form action="">
        {inputs.map((input) => (
          <Input
            key={input.id}
            id={input.id}
            name={input.name}
            placeholder={input.placeholder}
            type={input.type}
            value={values[input.name]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        ))}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Explanation:

As the previous answer explained, the error is in this line `value={values[input.name]}` and the reason for the error is that the object `values` cannot be indexed by any random string, the index has to be one of `values` declared properties (like `username`).

The solution is to give `inputs.name` a type that can be used as index of `values`:

```
const inputs: {
    id: string;
    name: keyof typeof values;
    type: string;
    placeholder: string;
  }[] = ...
```

Now the property `name` has a type of whatever keys in `values`. Now `input.name` can be used to index `values`.

Answer (score 6):

Your variable `values` is of the type `{ username: string; email: string; password: string; confirmPassword: string; }`. Accessing its contents can be done by calling `values.username` or `values['username']`.

Typescript can even infer something like this:

```
let key = 'username'
let username = values[key]
```

This is because `key` does not have the general type `string` in this instance, but is known to be of the type `'username'`, which is known to be able to index `values`.

Your code contains the line `value={values[input.name]}`. The variable `input.name` is of the type `string`. However, `values` cannot be indexed by any string, only specific ones. Typescript only knowns that `input.name` is a `string`. If you are certain, that your string can index the type, you can typecast the string with `index.name as keyof typeof values` and typescript should stop complaining.

Notice, however, that you are trying to use `input.name` as the key for `values`, but the names are `"UserName"` and `"Email"`. You should use `input.id` instead as the ids match the actual keys. Capitalisation is important.

Now the result of `values[index.name as keyof typeof values]` may still be of `any` type, because typescript does not know which value is actually returned. Because everything in `values` is a string you can just typecast is to string. In total you get `values[index.name as keyof typeof values] as string`.

Comment: Thank you for ur explanation. you shed some light me on insight into typescript :)